# R: basic Barplot from a named list

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart

I'm searching the web for more than 2 hours to find a way to have a bar plot of a list. I would like to have the names(my_list) as the x labels and the value of list elements as the height of them. But I really got confused with different syntax of R. Can any one give me a hint please?!

```
barplot(unlist(my_list))
```

Works, but no x-axes label of the elements.

```
barplot(unlist(my_list))
```

gets:

```
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 1):

So looking at this question, this seems like you are going down the right path. There might be something wrong with your list declaration. For example, if I define my list as

```
testList = list(first=1, second=2, third=3)
```

Which when printed in R by doing `print(testList)` looks like

```
$first
[1] 1

$second
[1] 2

$third
[1] 3
```

I am able to create the barplot in the way you described. I run the command `barplot(unlist(testList))` and I get the following graph back

[Barplot Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlF4A.png)

Hope this helps! If you are defining your list in another way, just comment and we can discuss that problem if needed.